# Como passar parâmetros Json, para consumir uma API C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

Estou tentando consumir uma API do PagSeguro de tranferência que pede para que seja passado o email de quem vai receber, o valor e a descrição, eu fiz de acordo com o modelo abaixo mas acho que não está correto.

Obs: apaguei o meu token e email na url da API.

```
public ActionResult FazerTransferencias()
{
    var uri = "https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/transfer/authorize?email=&token=";
    WebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";

    string receiverEmail = "vinicius_eugenio08@hotmail.com";
    string amount = "1.00";
    string description = "Transferência How2Code";

    String input = "{\"receiverEmail\":\"" + receiverEmail + "\",\"amount\":\"" + amount + "\",\"description\":\"" + description + "\"} ";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(input);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            return Json("Retornou");
        }
    }
```

Documentação da API: [https://dev.pagseguro.uol.com.br/reference#solicitando-autorização-1](https://dev.pagseguro.uol.com.br/reference#solicitando-autoriza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-1)

ao debugar o código a api retorno o erro 500.

detalhe na conta não tem dinheiro esse erro séria por esse motivo, ou é algum erro no código mesmo.

Comment: dá erro em qual linha? vejo um problema ai no seu código: o `StreamReader` deveria ser aberto após o using do `StreamWriter`

Comment: O erro aparece nessa linha var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); , após o StreamWriter.Close();

Comment: tentou colocar isso depois de terminar o StreamReader?

Comment: E qual é a descrição do erro 500?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta fazer algo assim. É mais simples e deve funcionar:

```
public string FazerTransferencias()
{
    var data = new
    {
        receiverEmail = "vinicius_eugenio08@hotmail.com",
        amount = 1,
        description = "Transferência How2Code"
    };

    string email = "x@x.com";
    string token = "12345";
    var result = new HttpClient().PostAsJsonAsync($"https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/transfer/authorize?email={email}&token={token}", data).Result;
    return result.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().Result;
}
```